# Ubuntu 16.04 shutdown & lock problem

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, lock

I am a new linux user. When I press the Shutdown option from  menu in my laptop don't shutdown and it's sign out from my sing in account  . And from menu my lock option don't work . How can I solve this problem ? And other thing from terminal shutdown now command work.